# RS485 Serial Communication not working with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, softwareserial, rs485

I am trying to control 2 devices with my arduino using RS485 communication. 
Basically switch on device 1 for 5 seconds when I send 'g' to the master. And switch on device 2 for e3 seconds when I send 'h' to the master.

I have a similar setup working with delays in the code I cannot use delays in the final version.

Here is the code I am using -

Master -

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>

#define NL 10
#define CR 13

SoftwareSerial Serial1(10,11); //RX, TX

String inputString = "";         // a String to hold incoming data
bool stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete
char prevChar = (char) 0;
char inChar = (char) 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char getdata = 'm';
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);

  if (stringComplete) {
    Serial.println(inputString);
    inputString.trim();
    //Serial.println("abc");
    if (inputString.length() == 1 && inputString.charAt(0) == 'g')  {
      Serial.println("Starting laser 1.");
      digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
      Serial1.print('1');
      //Serial1.print('h');
      Serial1.print(CR);
      Serial1.print(NL);
      Serial1.flush();
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    }
    else if (inputString.length() == 1 && inputString.charAt(0) == 'h')  {
      Serial.println("Starting laser 2.");
      digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
      Serial1.print('2');
      //Serial1.print('h');
      Serial1.print(CR);
      Serial1.print(NL);
      Serial1.flush();
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
    }
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
  }

  if (Serial1.available()) {
    while(Serial1.available() && getdata != '\n') {
      getdata = Serial1.read();
      Serial.print(getdata);
    }
    Serial.println("");
  }
}

void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    prevChar = inChar;
    inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    //Serial.println(inputString);
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
    // do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n' && prevChar == '\r') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Slave -

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

bool isLightOn = false;
int counter = 0;

int address = 2;

String inputString = "";         // a String to hold incoming data
bool stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete
char prevChar = (char) 0;
char inChar = (char) 0;

void timerISR() {
  if (isLightOn) {
    counter = counter+1;
    if (counter >= 20) {
      counter = 0;
      isLightOn = false;
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Timer1.initialize(100000);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(timerISR);

  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  //digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);
  if (stringComplete) {
    inputString.trim();
    //if (inputString.length() == 1 && inputString.toInt() == address) {
      isLightOn = true;
      digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    //}
  }

  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    prevChar = inChar;
    inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
    // do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n' && prevChar == '\r') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
/*
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    prevChar = inChar;
    inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
    // do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n' && prevChar == '\r') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
*/
```

My connections are something like this -

- Master - Uno,
- Slave 1 - Uno,
- Slave 2 - Nano

[image: Circuit Connection Diagram]

Comment: `Serial1.println("1")`; sends "1\r\n". no need to print the characters separately. `inputString = Serial.readStringUnil('\n');` reads all the input from Serial Monitor. but if you send only one character, why do you read into String?